# Can't Segue to another View Controller only on Device. SWIFT

Tags: iphone, xcode, swift, ios-simulator

I am trying to segue to another view controller, which works fine in the simulator. But when doing it on the device it just crashes and callback says:

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

I get the same callback is I try to segue through the storyboard like this:

```
func letsGoPressed(sender: UIButton!) {

        performSegueWithIdentifier("goToQuestions", sender: self)
}
```

or if I try to `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier` like this:

```
func letsGoPressed(sender: UIButton!) {

      let questionsGameVC: QuestionsGame = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("Questions") as! QuestionsGame
      var modalStyle: UIModalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyle.CoverVertical

     questionsGameVC.modalTransitionStyle = modalStyle

     self.presentViewController(questionsGameVC, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }
```

These both work on the simulator just not on the device!??!

Comment: Does it still work on your simulator if you reset the simulator and run it again? Does it still crash on your device if you delete and reinstall the app? Storyboards can sometimes get cached which can result in inconsistent results like this.

Comment: Thanks! deleted it and now it works! strange...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like the cached version of the storyboard didn't have a `goToQuestions` segue or a view controller with a `Questions` identifier.

Also you can delete `: QuestionsGame` here:

```
let questionsGameVC: QuestionsGame = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("Questions") as! QuestionsGame
```

Since you're explicitly casting the type using `as!`, there's no need to also declare the type.